# Input CSV data in to layers with Illustrator Scripting

Tags: javascript, csv, adobe-illustrator, windows-scripting

I'm very new to Illustrator Scripting. How to load data in csv file in to separate layers of illustrator file?
the data should be formatted with separate font styles and sizes prior to insert in to layers.

[image]

sample CSV data:

```
L1,L2,L3,L4,L5,VL5,SewP,Ref,Fname,Old,VL1,VL2,VL3,VL4
2,30,00,DNP,X SHORT,XSHT,T,55L,55L_2_XSHT_T.pdf,55L_WP_SD_S_Data Set 1,UK/AUS/NZ • 2,EUR • 30,CAN/US • 00,
2,30,00,DNP,SHORT,SHT,T,55L,55L_2_SHT_T.pdf,55L_WP_SD_S_Data Set 2,UK/AUS/NZ • 2,EUR • 30,CAN/US • 00,
2,30,00,DNP,REGULAR,REG,T,55L,55L_2_REG_T.pdf,55L_WP_SD_S_Data Set 3,UK/AUS/NZ • 2,EUR • 30,CAN/US • 00,
2,30,00,DNP,MEDIUM,MED,T,55L,55L_2_MED_T.pdf,55L_WP_SD_S_Data Set 4,UK/AUS/NZ • 2,EUR • 30,CAN/US • 00,
2,30,00,DNP,LONG,LNG,T,55L,55L_2_LNG_T.pdf,55L_WP_SD_S_Data Set 5,UK/AUS/NZ • 2,EUR • 30,CAN/US • 00,
2,30,00,DNP,X LONG,XLNG,T,55L,55L_2_XLNG_T.pdf,55L_WP_SD_S_Data Set 6,UK/AUS/NZ • 2,EUR • 30,CAN/US • 00,
2,30,00,DNP,SHORT/REGULAR,SHT_REG,T,55L,55L_2_SHT_REG_T.pdf,55L_WP_SD_S_Data Set 7,UK/AUS/NZ • 2,EUR • 30,CAN/US • 00,
2,30,00,DNP,REGULAR/LONG,REG_LNG,T,55L,55L_2_REG_LNG_T.pdf,55L_WP_SD_S_Data Set 8,UK/AUS/NZ • 2,EUR • 30,CAN/US • 00,
2,30,00,DNP,LONG/X LONG,LNG_XLNG,T,55L,55L_2_LNG_XLNG_T.pdf,55L_WP_SD_S_Data Set 9,UK/AUS/NZ • 2,EUR • 30,CAN/US • 00,
4,32,0,152/176-76-84,X SHORT,XSHT,T,55L,55L_4_XSHT_T.pdf,55L_WP_SD_S_Data Set 10,UK/AUS/NZ • 4,EUR • 32,CAN/US • 0,RU • 152/176-76-84
4,32,0,152/176-76-84,SHORT,SHT,T,55L,55L_4_SHT_T.pdf,55L_WP_SD_S_Data Set 11,UK/AUS/NZ • 4,EUR • 32,CAN/US • 0,RU • 152/176-76-84
```

Final result has to be populated as below.

[image]

Comment: He is on the move!!!

Comment: I can't believe it... You didn't even accept my answer as a correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// data -------------------------------------------------------------

var csv = '''L1,L2,L3,L4,L5,VL5,SewP,Ref,Fname,Old,VL1,VL2,VL3,VL4
2,30,00,DNP,X SHORT,XSHT,T,55L,55L_2_XSHT_T.pdf,55L_WP_SD_S_Data Set 1,UK/AUS/NZ • 2,EUR • 30,CAN/US • 00,
2,30,00,DNP,SHORT,SHT,T,55L,55L_2_SHT_T.pdf,55L_WP_SD_S_Data Set 2,UK/AUS/NZ • 2,EUR • 30,CAN/US • 00,
2,30,00,DNP,REGULAR,REG,T,55L,55L_2_REG_T.pdf,55L_WP_SD_S_Data Set 3,UK/AUS/NZ • 2,EUR • 30,CAN/US • 00,
2,30,00,DNP,MEDIUM,MED,T,55L,55L_2_MED_T.pdf,55L_WP_SD_S_Data Set 4,UK/AUS/NZ • 2,EUR • 30,CAN/US • 00,
2,30,00,DNP,LONG,LNG,T,55L,55L_2_LNG_T.pdf,55L_WP_SD_S_Data Set 5,UK/AUS/NZ • 2,EUR • 30,CAN/US • 00,
2,30,00,DNP,X LONG,XLNG,T,55L,55L_2_XLNG_T.pdf,55L_WP_SD_S_Data Set 6,UK/AUS/NZ • 2,EUR • 30,CAN/US • 00,
2,30,00,DNP,SHORT/REGULAR,SHT_REG,T,55L,55L_2_SHT_REG_T.pdf,55L_WP_SD_S_Data Set 7,UK/AUS/NZ • 2,EUR • 30,CAN/US • 00,
2,30,00,DNP,REGULAR/LONG,REG_LNG,T,55L,55L_2_REG_LNG_T.pdf,55L_WP_SD_S_Data Set 8,UK/AUS/NZ • 2,EUR • 30,CAN/US • 00,
2,30,00,DNP,LONG/X LONG,LNG_XLNG,T,55L,55L_2_LNG_XLNG_T.pdf,55L_WP_SD_S_Data Set 9,UK/AUS/NZ • 2,EUR • 30,CAN/US • 00,
4,32,0,152/176-76-84,X SHORT,XSHT,T,55L,55L_4_XSHT_T.pdf,55L_WP_SD_S_Data Set 10,UK/AUS/NZ • 4,EUR • 32,CAN/US • 0,RU • 152/176-76-84
4,32,0,152/176-76-84,SHORT,SHT,T,55L,55L_4_SHT_T.pdf,55L_WP_SD_S_Data Set 11,UK/AUS/NZ • 4,EUR • 32,CAN/US • 0,RU • 152/176-76-84'''

var lines = csv.split("\n");


// MAIN -------------------------------------------------------------

// make character styles
var FONT1 = make_style("font1", "ArialMT", 5.5);
var FONT2 = make_style("font2", "Verdana", 5.5);
var FONT3 = make_style("font3", "TimesNewRomanPSMT", 6.3);

// process lines
for (var i=1; i<lines.length; i++) {
    var data = get_data_from(lines[i]);
    make_layer(data.name)
    var text = make_text(data.contents);
    apply_styles(text);
    put_in_center(text);
}

// END

// functions --------------------------------------------------------

function make_style(style_name, font_name, size) {
    // try to add a new style
    try { var style = app.activeDocument.characterStyles.add(style_name) } 
    // or pick a style with the same name if it exists already
    catch(e) { var style = app.activeDocument.characterStyles.getByName(style_name) }
    style.characterAttributes.size = size;
    style.characterAttributes.textFont = textFonts.getByName(font_name);
    return style;
}

function get_data_from(line) {
    var arr = line.split(",");
    var L5    = arr[4];
    var Fname = arr[8].replace(".pdf", "");
    var VL1   = arr[10];
    var VL2   = arr[11];
    var VL3   = arr[12];
    var VL4   = arr[13];
    return {"name":Fname, "contents":[VL1, VL2, VL3, VL4, L5]};
}

function make_layer(layer_name) {
    var new_layer = app.activeDocument.layers.add();
    new_layer.name = layer_name;
}

function make_text(array) {
    var text = app.activeDocument.textFrames.add();
        text.contents = array.join("\n");
    return text;
}

function apply_styles(text) {
    // not the best piece of code, I'm sure it can be done better
    text.textRange.paragraphAttributes.justification = Justification.CENTER;

    FONT1.applyTo(text.textRange);

    var chars = text.textRange.characters;
    for (var i=0; i<chars.length; i++) {
        var ch = chars[i];
        if (ch.contents == "•") {
            FONT2.applyTo(ch);
            i++;
            i++;
            for (var j=i; j<chars.length; j++) {
                ch = chars[j];
                if (ch.contents != "\r") {
                    FONT3.applyTo(ch);
                    continue;
                }
                i=j;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

function put_in_center(obj) {
    var rect = app.activeDocument.artboards[0].artboardRect;
    var page_w = rect[2] - rect[0];
    var page_h = rect[1] - rect[3];
    var shift_x = page_w/2 - obj.width/2;
    var shift_y = -page_h/2 + obj.height/2;
    obj.position = [rect[0] + shift_x, rect[1] + shift_y];
}
```

[image]

**Update**

To read csv data from a file you need to replace this part:

```
var csv = '''
...
...
... '''
```

with:

```
var csv_file = File("c:/temp/data.csv");  // <-- here is the full path to the csv file
csv_file.open("r")
var csv = csv_file.read();
csv_file.close()
```

Or you can use `openDialog()` method if you want to select csv file via Open dialog:

```
var csv_file = File.openDialog();
csv_file.open("r")
var csv = csv_file.read();
csv_file.close()
```

Comment: Hat's off my friend !!!. You are the man of the day!!! Thank you very much for your effort and passion of helping me on this matter. As I don't have enough reputations , I may not able to mark this as the exact answer. If you don't mind I would like to request small favor. After generating above layers, will you be able to export all layers as separate pdf  and AI file. The name of each pdf is same as the layer name. Any way thank you again for your kind heart.

Comment: To export all layers to PDFs is not so simply task, as far as I can tell. Fortunately it's solved already: https://gist.github.com/TomByrne/7816376

Comment: Thanks brother for your humble guidance.

Comment: I didn't have much reputation to mark this as the solution at the time of your response. I have voted you now. If you don't mind can you adjust the code little bit so that external csv file could be uploaded rather than embedded text.

Comment: Okay. See my Update

Comment: thanks Yuri. Kindly let us know is there any book or video tutorial that I can refer to learn AI scripting?

Comment: Probably there is something in the wild. But I don't know exactly. I learned it just by examples, via googling. Unfortunately official Adobe Illustrator Scripting documentation is far from excellent. And actually most of the tricks you can see here are a bit outdated. Adobe has a new platform for scripting that looks almost as full-fledged web developing: https://medium.com/adobetech/scripting-for-cc-apps-via-cep-panels-579b2934b9c6

Comment: Yuri.  you are a very rare person with excellent qualities. You are a asset to this community. I think It's time to create Youtube  Channel and share your knowledge among others. This is a niche area. Programmers don't know designing and  designers don't know programming. There is a gap. This is a good area if you can start a channel to share your knowledge as a service.

Comment: Good idea. But my speaking English is even worse than my writing English. So the niche would be too narrow. ) But I will think about it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232959/discussion-between-hiran-and-yuri-khristich).

Comment: My friend, Please send your email. I need to contact you.

Comment: How can we do above process with a interface?

Comment: Hi, it depends on what you are going to call an interface. Say, the line `var csv_file = File.openDialog();` opens a dialog window to select a file with data, etc. This is an interface too.

Comment: Yuri_ can I get your mail address?

Comment: discord: yukhristich#9317

Answer (score 0):

as i understand correctly, you can't handle with making .json file parsing the data from .csv. Here is solution with csv2json. Don't forget to import and add this module to your project.

Good luck!

```js
server.get('/api/v1/graph', async (req, res) => {
  await fs
    .createReadStream(`${__dirname}/data/mydata.csv`) // here is the directory where .csv file is situated
    .pipe(
      csv2json({
        L1: Number,
        L2: Number,
        L3: Number,
        L4: String,
// and so on => graph : Type
      })
    )
    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('data.json'))
  res.json({ result: 'ok' })
})
```

Comment: Can't we do it with illustrator Scripting ? What is the mechanism of importing csv data and format above data based on the formatting rule and generate layers.

Comment: Sorry, I supposed u have troubles with converting nor drawing the data and already have implementation on illustarting

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I need importing and formatting for layers part.

Comment: can any expert help me on this matter ?