# Extendsript - Adobe Illustrator - Change Character Font Family/Style for each word inside TextFrame

Tags: javascript, styles, adobe-illustrator, extendscript

I'm new to AI and scripting.  I have a template I'm starting with.  Inside this template, there is a TextFrame (called CITIES_1).  Inside here is template text like:

CITY 1
123 Address Rd.
MyCity, MyState MyZip

CITY 2
567 Address Rd.
MyCity2, MyState2 MyZip2

The CITY 1 header is Helvetica Neue LT Std / 75 Bold
The rest of the info is Helvetica Neue LT Std / 55 Roman

I'm trying to dynamically change this content to city information I have in a file.

I've tried changing the TextFrame.contents but it uses the first font family/style for the whole thing.  Any idea on how to change the data while keeping the same "formatting"?

TIA!

```
var helBold = app.textFonts.getByName("HelveticaNeueLTStd-Bd");
var helRoman = app.textFonts.getByName("HelveticaNeueLTStd-Roman");
var bold = myDoc.characterStyles.add({ name: "HelveticaNeueLTStd-Roman" });
var roman = myDoc.characterStyles.add({ name: "HelveticaNeueLTStd-Roman" });
var currTF = templateLayer.textFrames.getByName("CITIES_1");
currTF.contents = "MYCITY\r123 MyAddress Dr.\rMyCity, ST 12345\r555.555.5555\r";
bold.applyTo(currTF.words[1]);
```

Comment: If you had tried something already, it would be better if you show that code.

Comment: You can use some examples (how to handle text styles) from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67251603/input-csv-data-in-to-layers-with-illustrator-scripting

Comment: I will look at your examples Yuri and see what I can do.  I will post code in separate comment.  The code will have previous attempts commented

Comment: var helBold = app.textFonts.getByName("HelveticaNeueLTStd-Bd");
var helRoman = app.textFonts.getByName("HelveticaNeueLTStd-Roman");

var bold = myDoc.characterStyles.add({ name: "HelveticaNeueLTStd-Roman" });
//var roman = myDoc.characterStyles.add({ name: "HelveticaNeueLTStd-Roman" });

var currTF = templateLayer.textFrames.getByName("CITIES_1");
currTF.contents = "MYCITY\r123 MyAddress Dr.\rMyCity, ST 12345\r555.555.5555\r";
bold.applyTo(currTF.words[1]);

Comment: I've added the code into your question (you can do it by yourself). So all you need is to apply some style to the every first word if paragraphs in the text frame?

Comment: Please add a screenshot -- how the result should look like. Since the template text in your question (two rows) doesn't fit with the text in the code (4 or 5 rows). It's impossible to guess what do you want to gain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code I suppose you have a city name on every second row (starts from the first row):

> MYCITY
>
> 123 MyAddress Dr.
>
> MyCity, ST 12345
>
> 555.555.5555

And you want to apply some style on every first word of each second row. Something like this:

> **MYCITY**
>
> 123 MyAddress Dr.
>
> **MyCity**, ST 12345
>
> 555.555.5555

It can be done with this code:

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;

// pick the text frame and fill it with the text
var curTF = doc.pageItems.getByName('CITIES_1');
curTF.contents = 'MYCITY\r123 MyAddress Dr.\rMyCity, ST 12345\r555.555.5555';

// make two styles
var roman = make_style('roman', 'ArialMT', 10);
var bold = make_style('bold', 'Arial-BoldMT', 14);

// apply style 'roman' on the text
roman.applyTo(curTF.textRange, true);

// loop through the text and apply the style 'bold'
// on the first word of every second paragraph
var paragraphs = curTF.textRange.paragraphs;
for (var i = 0; i < paragraphs.length; i += 2) {
    bold.applyTo(paragraphs[i].words[0], true);
}

function make_style(style_name, font_name, size) {
    var doc = app.activeDocument;
    try { var style = doc.characterStyles.add(style_name) }
    catch(e) { var style = doc.characterStyles.getByName(style_name) }
    style.characterAttributes.size = size;
    style.characterAttributes.textFont = textFonts.getByName(font_name);
    return style;
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I got it to work!  Thanks to your code (I tweaked it a bit to fit my needs... added color, position, etc.) I got it to work.  Your code help me understand characterStyles.  I added an array that says "--NEXT--" to denote headers... here is my code:  function applyStyles(text) { 
text.textRange.paragraphAttributes.justification = Justification.LEFT;
helRoman.applyTo(text.textRange);
helBold.applyTo(text.words[0]);
var words = text.words;
for(var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
 if(text.words[i].contents == "--NEXT--") {
 helBold.applyTo(text.words[i+1]);
text.words[i].contents = ""; }}}

Comment: Thanks again... now i have to figure out how to create a nextPage to link to another TextFrame because the list of cities is so long it runs off the page.

Comment: link to pic of the results:  [link](https://photos.app.goo.gl/nuuitJPv3hMrv6wW9)

Comment: Perhaps in your case (city = paragraph) it makes sense to use paragraph styles with or instead of character styles. As for the several linked text frames -- I have no ready solution (I'd use InDesign for such task). But I can try to figure it out as well. Let me know if you need help.

Comment: i've never used InDesign, but I will take a look at it today. I will let you know how it goes.